# react assign specific key of object as default prop

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, jsx

I've a react component like:

`ReactDOM.render(<someReactComponent someObjectParam={ 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} />, document.getElementById('someDivID'));`

I'm sure the `someObjectParam` will have `key1` and I want to make  `'key2'` as optional So, In my react component I tried something like:

```
var someReactComponent = React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            someObjectParam: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        },
        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                //even tried someObjectParam['key2']:'' 
                someObjectParam.key2: ''
            };
       }
       render: function () {.....}
       });
```

But I syntax error in `getDefaultProps`. Is there any way to define it properly?

P.S: I know a work around to do something like `this.props.someObjectParam.key2 || ''` in render function or set `key1` and `key2` as different props but I'm after a more declarative way of doing it and I can't define my whole object as default value for some other logic I'm doing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since the property is an object you have to return an object, but you can certainly return an object with just a specific key populated:

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
       someObjectParam: { key1: "default" }
    }
}
```

> I'm sure the someObjectParam will have key1 and I want to make  'key2'
>   as optional

If this is what you want to do than you really want to make `key1` and `key2` as *separate* properties, not a single property. There's no way to partially fill a default property.

You could apply some default logic in your `constructor` so you don't have to worry about it from your `render` function:

```
constructor(props) {
    props.objectParam.key2 = props.objectParam.key2 || "default";
    super(props);
}
```

If the property can be updated you'll need this same logic in `componentWillUpdate` as well. At this point I would say it isn't really worth it, just deal with it in your `render` function.

Comment: the `value1` may be anything it's not fixed string... I know I can set them has a seperate properties, but due to some restrictions on my side I can't do it

Comment: And as I said in my question `I can't define my whole object as default value for some other logic I'm doing`

Comment: Sorry I guess I read too quickly. Then the answer is simply "No, you can't do that." You *could* apply some default populating in your `constructor` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but I found it today researching this issue so here goes my answer.

A more "declarative" pattern is to merge someObjectProp into someObjectDefaults, like:

```
const defaults = { key2: "key 2 default value" }
const someObject = Object.assign({}, defaults, this.props.someObjectProp)

// or a nicer, ES6 syntax:
const someObject = { ...defaults, ...this.props.someObjectProp }
```

then use `someObject` instead of `this.props.someObjectProp` from there on

React's defaultProps does not *merge* when the prop is defined so you can't set "deep defaults" there.